# Play sound when download finishes

Tags: javascript, audio, google-chrome-extension

Hey guys am new to chrome extension development.I have decided to made a chrome extension which is same as the download manager. I am trying to add a feature like when the download item is finished an audio must be played. So i have tried researching about this and found out `onCreated` event.I think thisis what i have wanted..

So i have tried the code like

```
DownloadItem.prototype.onCreated = function() {
  if (this.state == 'complete') {
var c = new Audio('Link to an audio source');
c.play();
}
```

But it didnt do anything.I am unable to hear the sound after the item is finished downloading.

Here is my [manifest.json](http://pastebin.com/yePFD30h).

As per the edit..

The main code which plays role in audio is

## popup.js

```
if (chrome.downloads) {
  DownloadManager.loadItems();
  chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(item) {
DownloadManager.getOrCreate(item);
DownloadManager.showNew();
DownloadManager.startPollingProgress();
  });

  chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
var item = DownloadManager.getItem(delta.id);
if (item) {
  item.onChanged(delta);
}
  });

  chrome.downloads.onErased.addListener(function(id) {
var item = DownloadManager.getItem(id);
if (!item) {
  return;
}
item.onErased();
DownloadManager.loadItems();
  });

  chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
  if (delta.state.current == "complete") {
   var c = new Audio('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.mp3');
c.play();
}
});
```

## manifest

```
{"name": "__MSG_extName__",
 "version": "0.3",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "__MSG_extDesc__",
 "icons": {"128": "icon128.png"},
 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
 "19": "icon19.png",
 "38": "icon38.png"},
   "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"},
 "background": {"persistent": false, "scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "default_locale": "en",
 "optional_permissions": ["management"],
 "permissions": ["downloads", "downloads.open", "downloads.shelf", "notifications"]}
```

The whole code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/9wnQD5eq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's a wrong event. `onCreated` obviously is supposed to fire when a download is *created*, and so it is guaranteed *not* to be completed. And it won't fire again.

Next off, you're using [Chrome API events](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events) wrong.

1. They are not attached to a particular `DownloadItem`, but are dispatched globally, i.e. `chrome.downloads.onCreated`.
2. An event is not a function to be executed (like `onclick` on an HTML element), it's an object with a method `addListener` to attach handlers.

Putting it together, and taking a look at [`chrome.downloads` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged), you need this:

```
chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(delta) {
  if (delta.state.current == "complete") {
    // Play sound
  }
});
```

Comment: That's not very descriptive of the problem.

Comment: See i have added the code you have provided and i have added the audio and some code to play it ..but when the item finished downloading it doesnt produce any sound..here is the editted codehttp://pastebin.com/9wnQD5eq

Comment: it would be really helpful if you can help me ..:)

Comment: You've got some huge code dump, most of which is not relevant, and it doesn't say which file it is. Create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/), and edit your question _adding_ your minimal example code. Note that only links to code is discouraged on SO.

Comment: ..can you help me out now ??..i have ediited as per ur request

Comment: Which file is that? Background script? Are there any errors in the relevant console?

Comment: it doesnt provide any errors in the console.and its popup.html ..i have given my manifest file in the question.

Comment: Event listeners won't work in a popup. The popup page is destroyed, along with all listeners, whenever popup is closed.

Comment: so what can i do ??.. am new in this ..any ideas on how i can produce an audio after the download ?? it would be really helpful

Comment: Read the introductory Overview first (all of it) if you're new to this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview If you put my code into your background script it should work. Better yet, package the audio file locally.